# root shell isn't using --color=auto

Tags: bash

Does anyone know why the root user doesn't have a colour coded shell? It would seem to me the one person who navigates the file system the most is the root user, s/he would benefit most from the colour coding. Is it off for a reason? BTW I'm using bash.

Comment: Are you saying how to activate the `--color=auto` for the root account? Or are you asking why it isn't activated by default?

Comment: Well I'd like an answer to both actually.

Comment: Ok sure. Which version of Unix/Linux are you using?

Comment: I use a few different flavours mostly Debian based. (ubuntu, mint, debian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mode --color=auto is usually defined through an alias. In one of your configuration files you have defined `alias grep='grep --color=auto'`. You mention you're using bash, so chances are it is defined in your .bashrc file (`~/.bashrc`).

In order to activate it for root, you would need to add it in the root's .bashrc. If you want to add it for the whole system you can add it in the global bashrc file (usually found in `/etc/bash.bashrc`).

As to why it's not activated by default for root account, I guess it boils down to the choices made by your particular vendor. I know Ubuntu for instance discourages root login. It could explain why they chose to strip down some interactive features.